# text overflow ellipsis doesn't work in my case

Tags: css

As you can see in my demo, I want to do '...' if the users' name is too long. But even if I set a fixed width to the `<p>`, it won't work.

```
.userDetailWrap p{
    float:left;
    margin:0px;
    clear:both;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

demo http://plnkr.co/edit/0h05w6fyhBHPr1NvXTSC?p=preview

Comment: Setting a width *does* work.. http://plnkr.co/edit/rpWYAyDTUHy2yVptggfC?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting fixed width to the `p` works fine. You should also consider cross browser practices.

```
width:80px;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
-o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
-ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Check [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/C2G8H4eazFwXtAjgwSth?p=preview) out.